# Order Desc with Nulls Last in SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have the following SQLite statement in my app

```
SELECT _id, text, updateDate FROM question ORDER BY updateDate DESC
```

This returns all of the null values then the questions in order from most recently updated, to oldest.

How do I get the nulls to appear after the questions that are ordered properly while still maintaining the other sort?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT _id, text, updateDate FROM question  
ORDER BY CASE WHEN updateDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, updateDate DESC
```